# WebTestClient instance doesn't see dependency of Controller as injected

Tags: java, dependency-injection, spring-boot-test

I do some Test Configuration. I am surprised all is OK in first scenario but not in second.

### In scr/main/java, I got this Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class PostgressControllerSpringData {

    @Resource
    PersonneRepository personneRepository;

    @GetMapping("/persist")
    public ResponseEntity<String> persistOne() {
        Personne p = new Personne();
        personneRepository.save(p);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("persistence ok", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
```

### In scr/main/test, I got this configuration class

```
@TestConfiguration
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PostgressControllerSpringData getBean() {
        return new PostgressControllerSpringData();
    }
```

### Now, in a test class, when I do

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
public class SCRIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private PostgressControllerSpringData myController;

    @Autowired
    PersonneRepository dao;

    @Test
    public void m() {

        myController.persistOne();
        assertEquals(1, dao.findAll().size());
        // here, my test is successful
```

==> All is fine.

### But if I do that.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
public class SCRIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private PostgressControllerSpringData myController;

    @Autowired
    PersonneRepository dao;

    @Test
    public void m() {

        WebTestClient testClient =     WebTestClient.bindToController(myController).build();
```

==> The code stops with the message

> Injection of resource dependencies failed;
>   No qualifying bean of type PersonneRepository' available:

I am surprised because in my first scenario,
field `PersonneRepository` of instance `PostgressControllerSpringData` is well injected. But in second, Spring tells to me that injection fails!

Answer (score 0):

`DataJpaTest` is not intended to load controller and in general Web layer. Only database related beans (like DAOs) will be loaded.
This is also written in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html)

> > Can be used when a test focuses only (highlighted with bold :) ) on JPA components.

If you want to load also a web layer (and as a result being able to inject controllers into the test) consider using `@SpringBootTest` annotation instead